# Socket.io NPM install error specific to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: npm, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It appears that socket.io is causing my an NPM install error on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I deploy to EB no problem. I add socket.io to my package.json and deploy to EB I get an error. I remove it and it passes again.

I add socket.io via `npm i socket.io --save`, and the lines that's added to package.json is `"socket.io": "^2.0.4"`

I am able to reliably cause this failure or repair the issue by simply removing the above line from package.json or adding it back in. Any ideas on what the culprit could be?

I'm using the same node version locally and on aws

It's hard to track down the specifics of the error but here is the output from eb-activity.log

> Running npm install: 
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm
>   Setting npm config jobs to 1   npm config jobs set to 1   Running npm
>   with --production flag   Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for
>   more details.   Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in 
>         main()
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
>         node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
>         self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
>       File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
>         raise e   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm',
>   '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1
>   (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
>
> [2018-01-19T20:30:59.814Z] INFO  [3067]  - [Application update
>   shippable.lowy-api-dev.develop.111@42/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh]
>   : Activity failed. [2018-01-19T20:30:59.814Z] INFO  [3067]  -
>   [Application update
>   shippable.lowy-api-dev.develop.111@42/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook]
>   : Activity failed. [2018-01-19T20:30:59.814Z] INFO  [3067]  -
>   [Application update
>   shippable.lowy-api-dev.develop.111@42/AppDeployStage0] : Activity
>   failed.

I'm using node v 6.11.5 on Elastic Beanstalk and socket.io 2.0.4

Update; following the instructions from https://gist.github.com/jmar777/9281403 I SSH into my Elastic Beanstalk instance and manually run the npm install. Everything passes normally without error! The pre-install output is identical to the above error logs, but it runs just fine.

Why would I get that error when Elastic Beanstalk runs the install but not manually?